# How do I make an image full screen on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a gallery and I want each photo to go fullscreen when you click on it like this:

[image]

Currently, I have a click handler on each image that adds a class `zoom` to the clicked image. The CSS selectors I wrote only blow the image up and don't have it centered on the full page like in the example. Here is my code:

```css
.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  align-content: center;
  object-position: center;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.zoom {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<body onload="getPics()">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Photo Gallery</h1>
      <div class="gallery">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543517515-d6ff15a98642?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjQ0NDc3fQ&s=493802e93ec426171750ac2291e2867e"
        /><img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543517515-d6ff15a98642?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjQ0NDc3fQ&s=493802e93ec426171750ac2291e2867e"
        /><img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543517515-d6ff15a98642?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjQ0NDc3fQ&s=493802e93ec426171750ac2291e2867e"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

How can I change the `zoom` CSS so the image goes into a full screen mode?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50430187/8906637
please try this.
this will be helpful .

Comment: Better to refactor title, in a webview or desktop? CSS can be used for desktop apps too. It will be obvious when someone looks at the questions list.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's difficult to do this with zoom - you have to calculate depending on the current viewport etc dimensions and reposition the image.

Another way of doing it is by having an element that fills the whole viewport and has a high z-index but is normally not displayed. When the user clicks on an image it is set as the background of this large element, with background-size contain so it always exactly fits.

In this snippet clicking on the enlarged image gets rid of it.

```js
function getPics() {} //just for this demo
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery img');
const fullPage = document.querySelector('#fullpage');

imgs.forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fullPage.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img.src + ')';
    fullPage.style.display = 'block';
  });
});
```

```css
#fullpage {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body onload="getPics()">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Photo Gallery</h1>
    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543517515-d6ff15a98642?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjQ0NDc3fQ&s=493802e93ec426171750ac2291e2867e" /><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543517515-d6ff15a98642?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjQ0NDc3fQ&s=493802e93ec426171750ac2291e2867e"
      /><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543517515-d6ff15a98642?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjQ0NDc3fQ&s=493802e93ec426171750ac2291e2867e" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="fullpage" onclick="this.style.display='none';"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a jQuery "one-liner" that makes all images on the page clickable to go fullscreen:

`$(document).ready(function(){$("img").click(function(){this.requestFullscreen()})});`

Comment: jQuery is overkill for this -- `<img src="..." onclick="this.requestFullscreen()"/>`

Comment: @Meekohi - this will work for individual images, but does not *"make **all** images on the page"* clickable.

Answer (score 0):

It will works on all the images of the document you can also use a same class for all images

```
        $("image tag").click(function(){
```

Showing first the container we have to work on!

Then Giving HTML overflow hidden so that nothing will shown except the hidden container.

Then I just placed an Image Section in Hidden Container and applying CSS on it with jQuery .css(); method.

```
            $("#Hidden Container").fadeIn(200);
            $("html").css("overflow","hidden");
            $(".image_section").css("background","url("+$(this).attr('src')+")");
        })
```

After showing the whole screen I gave an Icon on corner and then exiting the Full Screen by .fadeOut(); method

```
        $(".fa_cancel_icon").click(function(){
            $("#full_page").fadeOut(200);
            $("html").css("overflow","auto")
        })
```

You also have to give Some CSS to Hidden Container like.

```
        height: 100vh!important;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: black;
        display: none;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
```

AND FOR THE IMAGE SECTION USE: Note use important on the background properties if it doesn't work:

```
        height: 100%;
        width: 75%;
        z-index: 9999;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
```