# Image fullscreen on click (Wordpress Image carussell)

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, image

I have a similar problem like this ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545077/image-fullscreen-on-click/50430187)). I want to edit my image carussel on my wordpress page, so that when I click on an image, it will be shown in full screen. If possible with close button.
The HTMl is:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fullscreen Image</title>
</head>

<body>

        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img class="swiper-slide-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Lichtenstein_img_processing_test.png">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img class="swiper-slide-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/1_aerial_yangshuo_panorama_2017.jpg/500px-1_aerial_yangshuo_panorama_2017.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Can someone give me an example for CSS or JS how I can do it (I do not know a lot of JS or jQuery)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your question different from the other similar question?

Comment: Because I cant edit the HTML. I can just add a new CSS or JS script. And the given answers in the other question does not work in my case. i Have tried them. Maybe there is just a simple edit needed, but I dont know how.

Comment: Okay, please convert your example code into a snippet and let me know when you are done. The importance of this change is that this way we will be able to play around with a reproducible version of your problem.

Comment: Ok, I converted my HTML code into a snippet.

Comment: You do not have an image to work with in the snippet.

Comment: I added images to the snippet

Comment: Have you tested your snippet? It is still blank for me.

Comment: Sorry, now it should work

Comment: It does. Written an answer. If it solves the problem that you have, then you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a few tricky operations. First, you need to be able to show things on full-screen. I did this by setting the `backgroundImage` of `body` and hiding everything else once `body` gets the `fullscreen` class. But we need to avoid propagating the event, so, if the image is clicked in fullscreen mode, then we can restore the normal view.

```js
    function makeFullScreen(event, image) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.source;
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url("${image.src}")`;
        document.body.classList.add("fullscreen");
    }
    
    function hideFullScreen() {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = '';
        document.body.classList.remove("fullscreen");
    }
```

```css
body.fullscreen {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body.fullscreen * {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html onclick="hideFullScreen()">

<head>
  <title>Fullscreen Image</title>
</head>

<body>

        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img class="swiper-slide-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Lichtenstein_img_processing_test.png" onclick="makeFullScreen(event, this);">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img class="swiper-slide-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/1_aerial_yangshuo_panorama_2017.jpg/500px-1_aerial_yangshuo_panorama_2017.jpg" onclick="makeFullScreen(event, this);">
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```