# Create button with JS and HTML by clicking image

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm making a website for a friend and the idea is that when someone clicks an image, it goes fullscreen. When the image is fullscreen, I want to display at the bottom a button that links to an S3 service to download the full-res image. The idea is to form the URL using some pre-defined routes + the name of the image (ex. folder1/subfolder/imgName.jpg). The thing is that I haven't managed to dynamically create and destroy the button (destroy when image isn't fullscreen).

I currently have the script that makes the images go fullscreen. I found [this script here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50430187/19745273) that does that.

This is the script that loads all the images:

```
<!-- Here goes the images -->
  <?php
  #$fi = new FilesystemIterator("../../showoff_images", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
  #printf("There were %d Files", iterator_count($fi));
  #$fi = iterator_count($fi);

    $directory="../../showoff_images/";
    $images=glob($directory . "*.jpg");
    $lazyload = "lazy";
    $divclass = "grid-item";
    $buttonId = "addButton";

    echo '<div class="grid">';
    foreach($images as $image) {
          echo 
            "
            <img id=". $buttonId ." data-enlargeable class=". $divclass ." src=" .$image." loading =". $lazyload .">
            ",  PHP_EOL;     
  }
  echo '</div>';
  ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I don't understand how to create the button programatically using the onClick event inside HTML. This is currently my code:

```
<!-- Creates button -->
  <script>
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = "Submit";
    btn.onclick = function () {
      createbutton("Button is clicked");
    };
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  </script>
```

Comment: When you post a question it really helps to paste the complete code that reproduces your problem (instead of expecting us to paste the code from another SO post...). Also, what exactly is the problem in the code?

Comment: @Kokodoko My bad, I did not clearly specify my question. I have updated the question to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Unrelated fyi: you have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute - which is invalid. `id`s must be unique

Comment: @brombeer Thank you! I'm not actually using that ID at the moment, but for sure I'd miss it.

Comment: `dynamically create and destroy the button`...why not just show and hide a button?

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, that could work too. Still the problem persists, not sure how to do it.

Comment: to show and hide a HTML element, well that's quite easy to google but you basically just change its "display" style property