# How do I load HD images on canvas full page using onclick event for each unique entry in my PHP-generated HTML code?

Tags: javascript

onclick Image Fullscreen for many references (one at the time)

I need to load the HD image of the room / apartment on canvas full page using onclick event for each of them when clicked on the link image. each image is named buy a uid. Also the HD image should be closed on click.

For page weight reason I can't go to all loaded and display when needed with HTML5 & CSS3 only.The html code is generated by PHP from a Mariadb table. The code shown is only a part of the code, i got more than 100 entries.

I found [Image Fullscreen on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545077/image-fullscreen-on-click) but I don't know how to change my html and the javascript so that work like i need to.

My HTML & CSS code:

HTML: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Our Room decorations</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Our Room Decorations</h1>
<article>
    <details>
        <summary>on region R</summary>
        <details>
            <summary>In Country X</summary>
            <details>
                <summary>In Hotel</summary>
                <h4>Location: Hotel Name, Street,GPS_x,GPS_Y</h4>
                <b class="liste">Room Number: 12B</b> (★★★☆☆) <img src="/images/link.jpg" id="UID" alt="Room Number: 12B" onclick="myscript" /><br/>
                <b class="liste">Room Number: 45</b> (★★★★★)<img src="/images/link.jpg" id="UID" alt="Room Number: 45" onclick="myscript" /><br/>
            </details>
            <details>
                <summary>Apartments</summary>
                <h4>Location: Building Name, street,GPS_x,GPS_Y</h4>
                <b class="liste">Floor: ground floor</b> Apt. #8 (★★★☆☆) <img src="/images/link.jpg" id="UID" alt="Apt. #8" onmouseover="myscript" /><br/>
                <b class="liste">Floor: 3</b> Apt. #35 (★★★★☆) <img src="/images/link.jpg" id="UID" alt="Apt. #35" onmouseover="myscript" /><br/>
                <b class="liste">Floor: 10</b> Apt. #108 (★★★★☆) <img src="/images/link.jpg" id="UID" alt="Apt. #108" onmouseover="myscript" /><br/>
                <br/>
                <h4>Location: Building Name, street,GPS_x,GPS_Y</h4>
                <b class="liste">Floor: 5</b> Apt. #52 (★★★☆☆) <img src="/images/link.jpg" id="UID" alt="Apt. #52" onmouseover="myscript" /><br/>
            </details>
        </details>
    </details>
</article>
```

---

CSS: styles.css

```
h1 {
    color: #b9b9eb;
}

li {
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

h4 {
    color: #87cce8;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

h3 {
    font-family: serif;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-family: serif;
    margin-left: 0;
}

a {
    color: lightblue;
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    color: #00ACF3;
    font-size: 125%;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
summary:focus {
    outline-style: none;
}
article > details > summary {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
details > li {
    margin-left: 24px;
}
details details {
    margin-left: 36px;
}
details details summary {
    color: #c8dbe9;
    font-size: 24px;
}
details details details summary {
    color: lightgrey;
    font-size: 20px;
}
summary {
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
b.liste {
    padding-left: 2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
summary {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```